# Can you register your app for the default "share" screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like the ability for my app to receive images that a user can share on their iPad/iPhone.  Is this possible?

I don't care what application the user is in, Alien Blue, Photos, Tumblr, etc...  I'm just curious if there is an iOS default "Send To" that I could register my application to on install.

Here are examples I've seen across iOS, was curious if I could add my own app to this list somehow?

http://cl.ly/image/0i2Y2G0W0K3p
http://cl.ly/image/1z1H0W1q342j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 8 you can add system-wide sharing options with extensions.

However, extensions are just a part you can bundle with your app.

Source: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/04/ios-8-share-menu-customize/

Comment: So this isn't possible in iOS 7?

Comment: No. in iOS 7 there is no possibility to add a custom sharing service as a system-wide option.

Comment: What about: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: That has nothing to do with with the sharing menu. That has to do with showing your app can open a certain fileformat so it will be displayed in an "open this file in" dialog.